# Processing Jars in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, github, jar, processing

I have recently started working with a friend on eclipse, using Processing.

All the commits are fine and we can Push and Pull them correctly, but there is one problem:

We import an external jar from proccessing ("`Core.jar`") which is saved on each one of ours computers.

Every time that we Pull a new commit, ("`Core.jar`") directory changes and we have to remove the jar and reload it so we can Run the code.

Ive searched about gitIgnore but I do the ("Reset Option" and the "Ignore option") but it doesn't seem to work since the Jars problem is again.

I use Github Desktop.

Comment: What you probably will have to do is do a specific commit that removes that Core.jar file from the application. Then update your friends and your own .gitignore files to ignore this jar file to prevent from being committed again.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it, please?

Answer (score 0):

As commented, if that jar is versioned instead of being generated or loaded, you should remove it from the repo first:

You can open a command-line from GitHub Desktop, and type:

```
git rm --cached -- Core.jar
git add .
git commit -m "record Core.jar deletion"
git push
```

Then your `.gitignore` rule should be immediately effective.
Said `.gitignore` should include "`*.jar`", or at least "`Core.jar`" (without the double-quotes)